# Glassfish asadmin to list running applications' ports

Tags: glassfish, asadmin

I'm using Glassfish 3+ and deploying the applications to application server. My glassfish instance's port not "8080". when i enter the Glassfish Admin Console and going to Running Applications , i can see the port number which works. For example : 43888. How i can see the port numbers running applications on command prompt? Which asadmin command with?

Comment: how about checking domain.xml?

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way is to use the following command (on UNIX/Linux):

```
asadmin get '*' | egrep -i '[._]port[=.][1-9v]' | sort
```

This gets you most all the port values that are being used in a domain.

Comment: im using win. i think asadmin command may tell us which port belong to glassfish instance.

Comment: Never heard of this "get" command, and I am running on a UNIX system (OS X ~ FreeBSD). -bash: get: command not found

Comment: Rahman: you should install CygWin anyway. It saves you a lot of time when using Windows.